# Angular Form value changes subscription destroys automatically, when form control is removed?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, valuechangelistener

I have a Form Array (generated based on Array of JSON response), where form controls are added/removed dynamically (for each object form control added to form array). I have a scenario like there can be 2 dependent fields, So I have subscribed to valueChanges. My question is, do I need to manually unsubscribe it or will it be unsubscribed automatically when I remove that form control/group from form array?

Comment: Always unsubscribe manual subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, try it out.

```js
export class App {
  f = new FormArray<any>([]);

  constructor() {
    this.f.push(new FormControl(null));

    const sub = this.f.controls[0].valueChanges
      .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('subscription ended!')))
      .subscribe();

    this.f.removeAt(0);
  }
}
```

You'll see that the `finalize` is never triggered, meaning that your subscription is still active.

Now, if you add `sub.unsubscribe();` before the line with `removeAt`, you'll see that the `finalize` is triggered, meaning that the subscription is closed as expected.

Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8rzuvh?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fmain.ts).